# How do I filter a datagridview with text?

Tags: c#

I'm making an application where we can see data from my database in a datagridview. I got to a point that I need to filter somethings and I'm only able to filter with "numbers" for example (IdProducts), this is the code I'm using:

```
string query= "SELECT * FROM  alunos where Estado="+textBox1.Text;
if(a.open_connection() == true)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, a.connection);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dataReader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;
    }
    
    dataReader.Close();
    a.close_connection();
}
```

in this code I'm trying to filter the column "Estado" which is text and it gives me this error,

> Unknown column 'A' in 'where clause'

"A" is what I'm trying to filter (is a camp from Estado column)

My question is how can I be able to filter with not only numbers but text too?

```
string query= "SELECT * FROM  alunos where Estado="+textBox1.Text;
if(a.open_connection() == true)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, a.connection);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dataReader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;
    }
    
    dataReader.Close();
    a.close_connection();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo need to change your code to use a parameterized query like this

```
string query= "SELECT * FROM  alunos where Estado=@state";
if(a.open_connection() == true)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, a.connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    MySqlDataReader dataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dataReader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;
    }

    dataReader.Close();
    a.close_connection();
}
```

The problem in your original code is caused by the fact that you concatenate the string value from the textbox without adding quotes around it. In this way the parser is fooled and thinks that you are naming a field and, of course, cannot find it.

However, *"resolving"* the problem simply adding single quotes around the textbox is not a real solution because you are opening your code to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) attacks. Instead, if you use a parameterized queries, you don't have your original problem, you avoid sql injection, you will not face other 'syntax errors' caused by the presence of single quotes in your textbox.text property and your database engine can optimize the query because parsing it just one time even if you call it more than one time.